# Contraction on continous functions with uniform norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The problem is this:
Let $G:C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1])$ be defined by $$(Gx)(t) = \int_{0}^{t} sx(s) ds$$ $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

I am supposed to show that $G$ is a contraction on $(C([0,1], d_{\infty})$. Here is what I've done so far:

\begin{align} d_{\infty}(Gx, Gy)& = \text{max} \|(Gx)(t) - (Gy)(t)\|, \: 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\ & =\text{max} \big\|\int_{0}^{t}sx(s)ds - \int_{0}^{t} sy(s) ds \big\|\end{align}

At this point my approach was to integrate by parts to hopefully separate $x$ and $y$ so I could end up showing $$d_{\infty}(Gx,Gy) \leq cd_{\infty}(x,y), \: 0 \leq c \leq 1$$ but that didn't really work out. Any tips/hints, full answers or semi-answers are very welcome and would help me out a lot.

Also, I'm not quite sure which tags I should put on this. The course this problem is from is called Linear Methods, and it seems to be closely linked with topology (perhaps like a "prequel")

Comment: $G$ is linear, so you want to show that there is a $c < 1$ with $\lVert Gx\rVert_{\infty} \leqslant c\lVert x\rVert_{\infty}$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\max_t |G(x)(t)-G(y)(t)| = \max_t \left| \int_0^t s (x(s)-y(s)) ds \right| \le d_{\infty}(x.y) \max_t \int_0^t s ds = \frac12 d_{\infty}(x.y) $$

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you so much. It really bugged me that I couldn't figure it out.